# error LNK2005 while implementing boost function pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, boost

I am trying this piece of code

demo.hpp

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;

typedef boost::function<int(int,int)>func;

class funcPointer
{
public:

    void add_call(func);
};
```

demo.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "demo.hpp"

void funcPointer::add_call(func f)
{
    cout << "Result of add: " << f(5,7) <<endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "demo.cpp"

int add(int x,int y)
{
    cout << "x: " << x <<endl;
    cout << "y: " << y <<endl;

    return x + y;
}

int main()
{
    funcPointer *fun = new funcPointer;

    fun->add_call(boost::bind(add, _1, _2));    

    return 0;
}
```

while compiling I am getting the following errors:

```
demo.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __thiscall funcPointer::add_call(class boost::function<int __cdecl(int,int)>)" (?add_call@funcPointer@@QAEXV?$function@$$A6AHHH@Z@boost@@@Z) already defined in main.obj
E:\vs_c++\boost_func_ptr\Debug\boost_func_ptr.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I don't understand what kind of error is this, Can somebody help me to solve this error??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `#include` source files!

In your case (and I'm only guessing here) the file `demo.cpp` is part of the project, so it gets compiled and linked to create the executable. The problem is that since you have also included that source file as a header file, the function is defined in `main.cpp` too.

In `main.cpp` you should include the *header* file `demo.hpp`.